# Filtered html ignores extra line breaks

Tags: 7, input-formats

I'm using the Filtered HTML input format without a WYSIWYG editor.

When editing text, if I put some text onto a new line by hitting <kbd>return</kbd>, when I save its fine.

However if I add another line (so there is a space between the 2 lines of text) by hitting <kbd>return</kbd> twice, when I save this extra line disappears. How can I stop this from happening? Thanks

So I can do this:

```
1
2
```

But I can't do this:

```
1

2
```

Comment: Is it possible to look at the source code before and after? Somebody may already know the answer to this, but seeing the before and after source code would be great.

Comment: The html once the comment is saved is every new line wraps its text in p tags. Before the comment is saved if i inspect the text element I can see my spacing in it but no mark up.

Comment: It sounds like it's removing blank paragraphs. D7 or D6?

Comment: 7        ..............

Comment: Like you said, I think whats happening is Drupal is converting new lines into new p tags, but double lines arnt adding a br tag or empty p tag. Id say this is a bug or at least a limitation as you cant alter this with filters at all.

Comment: But what is the output of the html?
Do you have a "p" or not?

Comment: I have a p tags around each new line, but no empty p tags or br where they would be needed to create an empty line.

Comment: And add a simple css rules with a margin bottom?

Comment: The configuration must be there for your content editor, if you can provide more information about the editor you are using, it will be easy for us to comment. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'content editor'? Im not using a WYSIWYG

Comment: If it is a normal textarea and youa are entering linebreaks, then you may try using nl2br().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a solution but its not perfect.

Ive turned on the 'Limit allowed HTML tags' filter for safety but turned all other filters off. This means the spaces appear in the code but do nothing as they arn't p or br tags.

Then I apply white-space: pre; to the element. Now all the spaces and new lines are preserved.

The issue with this is that a user could enter 100 new lines as there is no validation at all. Another problem is if this field is aggregated or used elsewhere on the site you would need to apply the css again to see the spaces.

Ill be very happy to accept a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Markdown Filter](http://drupal.org/project/markdown). It not only solves your problem, but gives a more intuitive input option.

If your users are used to using Markdown on StackOverflow, then they will love it ;)
In fact, StackOverflow was one of the first sites to integrate the Markdown format.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "P" tag (< p >) and "BR" tag (< br >) to the list of allowed tags on your filter HTML tags settings. You don't have to worry about security because since it is a filter HTML all the extra code like style inside the p tag will be remove.

**Note:** Make sure to check the option to  Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. < br > and < p >)

**Note 2:** if using a WYSIWYG editor like ckeditor make sure you have a set a condition like in note 1.

Comment: Ive already added those tags and p and br are in the html allowed tags list.

Comment: If I remove all filters except for 'Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)' then I can still only start a new line, I cant put a double spacing in the text.

Comment: Just as a comment do you check the user permissions are set to allow it to use the filter.

Comment: Also one more question: are the new lines been replaced by P's and BR's, but there are not enough space between them? if that is the case you just need a line in your CSS like p {margin-bottom:1.5em;}

Comment: Its not a permissions issue, the same thing happens when I post comments as the admin.

Comment: New lines are new P's but a double line doesnt add an empty P or a BR.

Comment: Try adding this to your CSS p {margin-bottom:1.5em;}

Comment: That isnt the issue. I already have a margin applied. I can see that no matter how many spaces I try and enter, each line that contains text is in p tags but all empty lines are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a wysiwyg editor. If you add a blank line then Ckeditor will create a p tag containing a html space.

I was however hoping to avoid using an wysiwyg as it needlessly increases the page size. I also dont know what its performance is link on mobile devices as its javascript based.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a perfect solution either. You can limit the number of consecutive newlines at any stage you like with regex - client-side presave, server-side presave, server-side pre-output, client-side output.

Here's an example for server-side pre-output modification in your theme's template.php file. The plain_text format can be any text filter of your choice and the null case covers plain text (when filter not set). I'm limiting the max newlines to 2 (using `{3,}` for 3 instances and above). My generalised regex covers \r newlines as well but this wouldn't be necessary in this use case.

```
function YOURSUBTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_type'] == 'text_long' &&  // Makes sure this is a text_long field type.
    isset($variables['element']['#items'][0]) && 
    (!isset($variables['element']['#items'][0]['format']) ||
    $variables['element']['#items'][0]['format'] === 'plain_text')
  ) {
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $index => $value) {
      $markup = isset($variables['items'][$index]['#markup']) ? $variables['items'][$index]['#markup'] : '';
      $markup = preg_replace("/[\r\n]{3,}/", "\n\n", $markup);
      $variables['items'][$index]['#markup'] = nl2br($markup);
    }
  }
}
```